# How to check if variable is a CFString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I am trying to set some text on a label

```
descriptionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:mySTUser.bio];
```

The bio property of mySTUser is an NSString. Sometimes it is not an NSString when I set it. How can I check if mySTUser.bio is an NSString so I can prevent it from being assigned to my label text?

Comment: What else might it be, if not a string? Also, you shouldn't use `stringWithFormat:` without a format string. It should either be `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", mySTUser.bio]` or `[NSString stringWithString:mySTUser.bio`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (![mySTUser.bio isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    // its not an NSString
}
```